# Expand div container with animation with text in it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working with website, i made the div expand and hidden the text by using some simple css and js. Anyone can teach how to i make text expand together with transition?
FYI I'm have limited knowledge on web design, sorry if my code is messy.

```html
    <html>
    <style>

    body, html {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
    }

    p.italic { 
 font-size: 150%;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-style:italic;
    }

    p { 
 font-size: 100%;
 line-height: 25px;
    }

    h1 { 
    font-size: 400%;
    }

    .container1 {
    height: 80px;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    }

    .container1expanded {
    height: 280px;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    line-height: normal;
    }

    .container1 h1 { 
    font-size: 400%;
    line-height: 40px;
    }

    #container1p {
    display: none;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    }
    <body>
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function expand(){
        document.getElementById("container1").style.height= "280px";
        document.getElementById("container1p").style.display= "block";
    }

    </script>
    <div class="container1" id="container1">
    <h1 onclick="expand()">Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <div id="container1p">
    <p class="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur                                             venenatis eget felis at tempor. Phasellus bibendum auctor massa condimentum venenatis. 
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "make text expand together with transition"? Can you describe what that means or what you want to see happen instead?

Comment: Just a hint: You are opening a `<script>` tag inside the `<html>` tag and then closing it inside the `<body>` tag. This HTML is not valid. You may want to check out something like [this HTML introduction](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_intro.asp)

Comment: @MichaelCoker You really don't understand what that means? The OP wants to animate the text as the `div` expands rather than have the text just visible at full size when the `div` expands. Seems pretty clear.

Comment: @ScottMarcus if I was certain of what OP's trying to do, I wouldn't have asked. So I'm asking for clarification so I don't have to make an assumption. "OP wants to animate the text" - animate how? Animate what? You're animating `scale()` and that's cool, but maybe OP wants to animate `opacity` or have the text fly down or in from the side or something. I don't know, so I'm asking if they have a specific expectation or if they just want people to come up with some any sort of animation.

Comment: @MichaelCoker like making text already there when i expand the div instead of text suddenly appear

Comment: @haoyin I'm not sure what you mean. The text is already there for me, and as the div expands, the text is revealed as the div expands...

Comment: @haoyin I submitted an answer that has the text reveal as the element expands instead of it suddenly appearing. Does that help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `overflow: hidden` to the expanding element, the text won't just pop in automatically on the page - the text will be hidden/clipped in the expanding element by default, and as it expands, it will reveal text as the height increases. I also adjusted the base height of the expanding element.

```html
    <html>
    <style>

    body, html {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: black;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
    }

    p.italic { 
 font-size: 150%;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-style:italic;
    }

    p { 
 font-size: 100%;
 line-height: 25px;
    }

    h1 { 
    font-size: 400%;
    }

    .container1 {
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:50px;
    margin-right:50px;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    }

    .container1expanded {
    height: 280px;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    line-height: normal;
    }

    .container1 h1 { 
    font-size: 400%;
    line-height: 40px;
    }

    #container1p {
    display: none;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    }
    <body>
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function expand(){
        document.getElementById("container1").style.height= "280px";
        document.getElementById("container1p").style.display= "block";
    }

    </script>
    <div class="container1" id="container1">
    <h1 onclick="expand()">Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <div id="container1p">
    <p class="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur                                             venenatis eget felis at tempor. Phasellus bibendum auctor massa condimentum venenatis. 
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: achieved my ideal design by simply adding a line, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

All you should have to do is include font-size for the before and after inside of the element that is transitioning.

```
.container1 {
height: 80px;
background-color:white;
margin-left:50px;
margin-right:50px;
font-size:18px;
transition: all 2s ease;
}

.container1expanded {
height: 280px;
font-size:28px;
transition: all 2s ease;
line-height: normal;
}
```

This is buggy if you try to transition two properties on the text at the same time, but should work fine if only transitioning its font-size:

Answer (score 0):

If you default the content to have a `transform:scale(0,0)` and set the content for a `transition` animation, you can animate the contents in much the same way as you are currently animating the container.

I would suggest you not set individual styles though. It's easier to just add and remove classes as necessary.

Also (FYI), your HTML is invalid as you have your `style` outside of `head` or `body` and you have no `head` at all.

See the JavaScript and CSS comments for details:

```js
// Get DOM references
var h1 = document.querySelector(".container1 > h1");
var container1 = document.getElementById("container1");
var container1p = document.getElementById("container1p");
var pars = document.querySelectorAll("#container1p p");

// Set event handlers in JavaScript, not in HTML
h1.addEventListener("click", expand);

function expand(){
    // Expand the container and show it by adding/removing classes
    container1.classList.add("container1expanded");
    container1p.classList.remove("hidden");
    
    // We need a short delay to let the UI update to show the container before
    // we animate the container's contents
    setTimeout(function(){
      // Loop over nested paragraphs
      for(var i = 0; i < pars.length; i++){
        // Scale the contents back to 100% from their default of 0
        pars[i].style.transform = "scale(1,1)";
      }
    }, 15);
}
```

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

p.italic { 
  font-size: 150%;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-style:italic;
}

p { 
  font-size: 100%;
  line-height: 25px;
}

h1 { 
  font-size: 400%;
}

.container1 {
  height: 80px;
  background-color:white;
  margin-left:50px;
  margin-right:50px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

.container1 h1 { 
  font-size: 400%;
  line-height: 40px;
}

/* content1p uses this class by default*/
.hidden {  display:none; }

/* This class is added when the container needs to be expanded*/
.container1expanded {
  height: 280px;
  line-height: normal;
}

/* This sets up animations on the contents */
#container1p {
  transition: all 2s ease;
}

/* This initializes the contents to a size of 0 and sets up the animation */
#container1p p {
  transform:scale(0,0);
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1" id="container1">
  <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
  <div id="container1p" class="hidden">
    <p class="italic">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur                                        venenatis eget felis at tempor. Phasellus bibendum auctor massa condimentum venenatis. 
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try something like this dont forget to include Jquery
[codepen simple animation](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEjdBr)

```
<div>
  <h1>Hello World</h1>
  <p>Hello world will the first animation that Lorem will make</p>

</div>
div {
  margin:0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width:290px;
  height:80px;
  background-color:blue;
  overflow:hidden;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

    p {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -20%;
      opacity:0;
       transition: .5s .5s ease;
    }

$('div').click(function(){
  $('div').css({width:'400px'});
  $('div').css({height:'400px'});
  $('p').css({opacity:'1'});
   $('p').css({bottom:'80%'});
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP not forget to include JQuery when they are not asking for a JQuery solution?